# Benchmark concurrent connections on Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, websocket, benchmarking, socket.io, nowjs-sockets

i am playing around with nodejs and would like to get some guide on how to benchmark concurrent connections on a websocket in nodejs using things like nowjs, socket.io and etc.

Comment: What do you want to benchmark? CPU usage, throughput? etc?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [siobench](https://github.com/mixu/siobench).

Comment: Thanks! will check out the siobrench but it´s the all over brenchmark of the server setup we have so with real client connection and etc.